# Android: ListView OnItemClick show Toast

Tags: android, json, listview, toast

I'm working on a Android app but I'm stuck at a really little thing.

I've created a dynamic ListView, it's pulling data from my database.
But now if I click on a specific line in the ListView it should show me a toast with the ID.

But I can't seem to get that working..

Can somebody give me a hand with that?

Cheers,
Patrick

This is my code

```
package wvv.zondag.app;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;

public class WedstrijdenJSONParser extends ListActivity{

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.wedstrijdenlist);

    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter(
            this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
            this.populate()));
}

private ArrayList<String> populate() {
    ArrayList<String> items = new ArrayList<String>();

    try {
        URL url = new URL
        ("http://www.wvvzondag2.nl/android/fillwedstrijden.php");
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection =
            (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        urlConnection.connect();
        // gets the server JSON data
        BufferedReader bufferedReader =
            new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    urlConnection.getInputStream()));
        String next;
        while ((next = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null){
            JSONArray ja = new JSONArray(next);

            for (int i = 0; i < ja.length(); i++) {
                String var = "";
                JSONObject jo = (JSONObject) ja.get(i);
                var = jo.getString("Tijd");
                var = var+" - "+jo.getString("Wedstrijd");
                items.add(var);
                }
        }
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return items;
}
```

}

---

Sorry for the late reply, thanks for the piece of code, but now it's showing the exact same thing as the list view is showing, Tijd(Time) and Wedstrijd(Match) but I would like to see the ID when I click on a listview item

My field is called ProgrammaID how can I manage to get that one showing in the toast?
Maybe I need to call it first in my JSONArray ?

Cheers,
Patrick

Comment: a part of the code is missing - the one with the toast...

Answer (score 5):

Add this to your code

```
    @Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id){
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
             Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
            ((TextView) v).getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
               /*v passed in as an argument is the view in your listitem which is clicked.If you want to get access to the adapter just use this.getListAdapter().*/



}
```

Comment: Close. You don't need to call getText() on the view because you are already getting a handle on the id and that's what he want's to display. But good answer +1

Comment: @FrankSposaro Thanks, I hope the OP is able to figure that out himself now :-)